# Why are the input box variables switching to null after the first iteration of a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some simple VBA code to update the x-axis of a lot of time-series charts in an excel document.

The issue I'm having is that after the first iteration of the loop, start_date and end_date variables become "".  I'm not sure why the variables are disappearing.  The macro does work for the first chart, but crashes after that because of the variable issue.

This is my code:

```
Sub xaxis_reset()

Dim start_date As Variant
Dim end_date As Variant
Dim ws As Integer
Dim obj As Integer

start_date = InputBox("Start Date")
end_date = InputBox("End Date")
ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2

         For w = 1 To ws
            obj = Worksheets(w).ChartObjects.Count
                For Z = 1 To obj
                    Worksheets(w).ChartObjects(Z).Activate
                         With ActiveChart
                              .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = start_date
                              .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = end_date
                         End With

                Next Z
         Next w

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you call the macro? w and Z are not defined. The problem might come from the chart activation, try removing it.

Comment: @VincentG I tried taking out the chart activation and I'm still having the same problem.  My conclusion is that this is an excel bug.  When I'm running the code excel randomly closes.  It's closed while I'm stepping through the code, it's closed when the code crashes and I click "debug" or "end."  For some reason Excel really hates the above code.

Comment: Why activate the chart and then set the axes? You should simply be able to say "With Worksheets(w).ChartObjects(Z)". I am not seeing anything that should be resetting your variables as well. Are you sure they are being reset within the loop?

Comment: @BrandonBarney thanks for the code optimization tips.  I agree that there is no reason to activate the chart.  I guess it's not really the loop that is resetting the variable, it is the .Axes(xlcategory).MinimulScale = start_date that resets the variable.  I've monitored the variable values and after that line of code the start_date goes from something like "08/16/2016" to "???????."  I actually just noticed that as different lines of code execute below it, the number of question marks change too.  Really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from declaring all your variables (w, z), you have to be smart about how you pass values to the axis limits. Your input boxes provide dates as strings. The values of `start_date` and `end_date` do not become "", but for some reason the strings are only interpreted correctly the first time through the loop. And for some reason, passing strings to a chart axis makes Excel remarkably unstable.

In the code below, I use `DateValue()` to convert these to actual dates, and pass these into the chart.

```
Sub xaxis_reset()
  Dim start_date As Variant
  Dim end_date As Variant
  Dim w As Long, ws As Long
  Dim z As Long, obj As Long

  start_date = InputBox("Start Date")
  end_date = InputBox("End Date")
  ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2

  For w = 1 To ws
    obj = Worksheets(w).ChartObjects.Count
    For z = 1 To obj
      Worksheets(w).ChartObjects(z).Activate
      With ActiveChart
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = DateValue(start_date)
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = DateValue(end_date)
      End With
    Next z
  Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  That's very interesting that passing a string through to a chart axis makes excel crash like that.  I wasn't thinking about the data time of the input like I should've.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not surprised about this particular case: Excel charts are fussy about inputs. I'm also not too surprised about Excel crashing, since Excel 2013 and especially 2016 seem to crash a lot, much more than 2007 and 2010. Excel now crashes almost as much as I remember Excel 4.0 used to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted a little your code (see below), and it seems to be a bug in how Excel set the properties (not always, but often modifying the variable used to set them to other values). A workaround (used in the code below) would be to use a buffer variable.

```
Sub xaxis_reset()

    Dim start_date As Variant, start_buffer As Variant
    Dim end_date As Variant, end_buffer As Variant
    Dim w As Integer
    Dim obj As ChartObject

    While Not IsDate(start_date): start_date = InputBox("Start Date"): Wend
    While Not IsDate(end_date): end_date = InputBox("End Date"): Wend

    On Error Resume Next
    For w = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2
        For Each obj In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).ChartObjects
            start_buffer = start_date: end_buffer = end_date
            Debug.Print w, start_date, end_date, start_buffer, end_buffer, (start_date = start_buffer), (end_date = end_buffer)
            obj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = start_buffer
            Debug.Print w, start_date, end_date, start_buffer, end_buffer, (start_date = start_buffer), (end_date = end_buffer)
            obj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = end_buffer
            Debug.Print w, start_date, end_date, start_buffer, end_buffer, (start_date = start_buffer), (end_date = end_buffer)
        Next obj
        Set obj = Nothing
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: All 3 debug.print should display the same thing, but often they are not.

Comment: Thanks for the code!  My excel is still shutting down when I run it.  But I've been getting a new error.  Now when I try to do anything excel is giving me an "Out of Memory" dialogue box.  So now I have a new direction to look in.  Must be some sort of an excel memory issue that is causing the variables to corrupt.